# add ssh to system start up in ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ssh

Is it possible to add this command in system start up ?
or even autostart when it gets closed automaticly(unknown Reason) ?

"ssh -fNg -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 User@10.10.1.20"

im using the above command to get php PDO connect to mysql server in another machine

through ssh Protocol.

last day this connection closed automaticly and now im going to avoid that mistake with

making some fail-safe method.

method. i find this file /etc/ssh/ssh_config but in this article

http://www.howtogeek.com/75007/stupid-geek-tricks-use-your-ssh-config-file-to-create-aliases-for-hosts/

it said i should modify ~/.ssh/config instead. im kinda lost atm.

is it possible to make php check for ssh connection if none available make one ?

like in another file "config.ini" stablish the ssh batch and then call mysql ?

Comment: Perhaps using a `crontab` entry labeled `@reboot`

Comment: first use `autossh` instead of of plain `ssh` to manage reconnect after failures. then add the `autossh` command to your startup scripts to survive reboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a cronjob that runs every minute:

File: /etc/crontab

```
* * * * * youruser if [ 0 == $(netstat -ntlp | grep :3306 | wc -l) ]; then /usr/bin/ssh -fNg -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 User@10.10.1.20; fi;
```

You might need to specify your configuration with -F /absolute/path/to/ssh.config for SSH key etc.